# can't install QT4 on linux Mint

Tags: linux, qt4, cmake, vpn, linux-mint

I am trying to compile vpnshrew with CMAKE on linux mint.
However QT4 is missing and I have already tried everything  with no success. The starting line it's this dependency error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libqt4-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt4-core : Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libqt4-test (= 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
           Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
           Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have already tried lots of solutions. Namely

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqt4-core libqt4-gui`.